# Using @font-face for buttons with icons and text

Tags: css, user-interface, fonts, font-face, user-experience

The other day I was cruising around and stopped on http://www.justbenicestudio.com/studio/websymbols which had a nice little article on using @font-face for icons in websites. To quote the author, "There are those points in every interactive designer's career when he becomes fed up with producing the same set of graphics all over again for every website he designs."

I was curious if @font-face would work for the app that I work on. [Check out the test](http://lab.atworkinthecloud.com/font-icon-test/).

It's not perfect so I'm looking for suggestions and opinions before I start implementing this. Do you think it's too soon? A waste of time? Or is it the most awesome thing since ajax?

Comment: Opinion questions are not really the type to be asking on this site (since there is no "solution"). Having said that, I think it is a great use of @font-face.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest that it's too soon, most browsers support @font-face so you will be relatively safe but I don't see any good reason not to play it safe and produce the image. You're probably saving the user more time and bandwidth by giving them the one small image than the entire font. If you use a photo editor like photoshop or gimp, just keep your files and they will be ready for the next time you need them.

Answer (score 0):

I have used @font-face only on text, but in that link you posted the button looks great. The only inconsistency I find is with cross-browser "compatibility" (but only from a design point of view). It's minor issues, though, and non-existent if you are designing for mobile (you mentioned app). Browsers render the font differently when it's text (for example, IE9 is not picking up the italics, but the render is less pixelated than chrome).

I think it's an issue of adaptability vs looks. Buttons made with images (preferably sprites, for my taste) will always look good, but you have to edit the images every time you want to make a new button. Buttons with @font-face are easy peasy to duplicate and modify, plus they might help with seo, but you have the browsers rendering difference.